# Change Query String Value in IIS URL Rewrite Rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I have tried multiple combinations so far but no luck. I have a URL like below.

```
https://teams.company.com/Search/pages/results.aspx?url=https://teams2017.company.com/sites/hrdepartment
```

I want to create a rule that will change the query string value from **teams2017** to **teams** only, like below.

```
 https://teams.company.com/Search/pages/results.aspx?url=https://teams.company.com/sites/hrdepartment
```

I am using IIS 8.5 with IIS Rewrite rule installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="teams2017 to teams" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Search/pages/results.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)teams2017(\.company\.com.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?{C:1}teams{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I don't know how you guys do this but its brilliant. A big thanks Victor for helping me out. It was really helpful. I wish i could learn this in some easy way. Once again thanks much.  :)