# ASP.NET rewrite redirect url on IIS (for Facebook social login)

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, facebook-login

I have an application that is behind a reverse proxy and when the user is trying to log in with a Facebook account, it fails because the redirect uri is an internal uri, instead of the public domain.

To come around this I want to rewrite redirected url.

This is the flow:

1. User logs in to Facebook
2. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook` nuget package takes over the authentication process
3. A redirection (302) GET request happens to this url:

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id={clientid}&scope=public_profile,email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-facebook&state={longstring}`

And this is the part that I want to rewrite:

`redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-facebook` to

`redirect_uri=https://mypublicdomain.com/signin-facebook`

Is this possible with IIS Url rewrite module?
I tried to configure it but couldn't get it to work.

(on the server I'm using ASP.NETCORE 1.1.2)

```
<outboundRules>
    <remove name="Rewrite Location Header" />
    <rule name="Rewrite Location Header" preCondition="IsRedirection" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^https:\/\/(.*&amp;redirect_uri=)([^&amp;]*)(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}https://google.com{R:3}" replace="false" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Make sure to use the `{QUERY_STRING}` input to match against and ensure you have `Rewrite` as the action type.

A similar solution you could use as a starting point can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718902/change-query-string-value-in-iis-url-rewrite-rule)

Comment: I updated my post with an example, but it still doesn't work. Just to be sure I'm not fundamentally wrong: when a server redirects, it sends back a new url to the client and the client makes a GET request to that new URL. 
So what I'm supposed to do is to rewrite the Location field in the Response Header of the redirect before it gets sent to the client.